# Filter String/Array for multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, npm, discord, discord.js

This is my code below, basically i want the bot to check two things. The users message needs to contain "how" + either "doing" or "bread". It works perfectly when i use only "doing" but not when I add the "bread" condition.
I need a clean and simple solution for this and hope someone can help me, bc for me thats the most logical way in archiving what i need :D

```
if(msg.content.includes("how") && msg.content.includes("doing" || "bread") ){

    if(msg.author != token){ 
        msg.lineReply("I am good sir")
        }

}
```

Comment: Have you checked what `"doing" || "bread"` does?

Comment: i cant find the difference to my code :D u mean without the bracets ? That wouldnt work since i am using the .includes function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
if(msg.content.includes("how") && (msg.content.includes("doing") || msg.content.includes("bread")) ){

    if(msg.author != token){ 
        msg.lineReply("I am good sir")
        }

}
```